# How do I order a bargraph to be positioned in between tick marks?

Tags: java, apache-poi, bar-chart

I added an example in the pictures below of what I want.

This is what I get.
[image: What I get]

This is what I want.
[image: What I want]

I've been searching through the the library to try to find something to make this change but I can't seem to find it.

Alternatively, is there a way to add padding to the top or bottom? The main issue is I don't want a bar touching the top or bottom border of the chart.

This is an XDDFChart, here is relevant code.

```
  XDDFCategoryAxis leftAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
  leftAxis.setTitle("Name");


  XDDFValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
  bottomAxis.setTitle("Volume");
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code which produces what you get. As the question is now, it not even shows what kind of chart (XSLFChart, XSSFChart or XWPFChart) you exactly wants to create.

Comment: Or try [XDDFValueAxis.setCrossBetween](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFValueAxis.html#setCrossBetween-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisCrossBetween-) to [AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/AxisCrossBetween.html#BETWEEN).

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you! That worked. I was looking at the wrong Axis. I was looking in the Category Axis since in my code I have the left axis as the category and bottom axis as the value.  



`XDDFCategoryAxis leftAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
      leftAxis.setTitle("Name");


      XDDFValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
      bottomAxis.setTitle("Volume");
      bottomAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);`

Do you want to add your answer below so I can choose it as best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bar charts the value axis should have set `crossBetween val="between"`, so the value axis crosses the category axis between the categories. Else first and last category is exactly on cross points and the bars are only half visible.

Also the left axis never will be the category axis and bottom axis never will be the value axis, even not for bar charts which displays `BarDirection.BAR` instead of `BarDirection.COL`. There only  the `XDDFBarChartData`'s bar direction is different. The axes remain the same.

So for an `XDDFChart` in general, a bar chrat having `BarDirection.BAR` should be like:

```
...
// create axis
XDDFCategoryAxis categoryAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
categoryAxis.setTickLabelPosition(AxisTickLabelPosition.NONE);
XDDFValueAxis valueAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
valueAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
// Set AxisCrossBetween, so the left axis crosses the category axis between the categories.
// Else first and last category is exactly on cross points and the bars are only half visible.
valueAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

// create chart data
XDDFBarChartData data = (XDDFBarChartData)chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, categoryAxis, valueAxis);
data.setBarDirection(BarDirection.BAR);
 ...
```

Complete example creating a `XWPFChart` in a `Word` document:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordXDDFChart {

 // methode to set title in the data sheet without creating a Table but using the sheet data only
 // creating a Table is not really necessary
 static CellReference setTitleInDataSheet(XDDFChart chart, String title, int column) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = chart.getWorkbook();
  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(0);
  XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(column); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(column);
  cell.setCellValue(title);
  return new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 0, column, true, true);
 }

 // methode to fill a series data into the underlying sheet
 static void fillSheet(XDDFChart chart, XDDFDataSource<?> categoryData, XDDFNumericalDataSource<?> valuesData) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = chart.getWorkbook();
  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  int numOfPoints = categoryData.getPointCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++) {
   XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i + 1); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(i + 1); // first row is for title
   XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(categoryData.getColIndex()); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(categoryData.getColIndex());
   cell.setCellValue(categoryData.getPointAt(i).toString());
   cell = row.getCell(valuesData.getColIndex()); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(valuesData.getColIndex());
   cell.setCellValue(valuesData.getPointAt(i).doubleValue());
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try (XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument()) {

   // create the data
   String[] categories = new String[]{"C1", "C2", "C3"};
   Double[] valuesA = new Double[]{300d, 20d, 10d};

   // create the chart
   XWPFChart chart = document.createChart(15*Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER, 10*Units.EMU_PER_CENTIMETER);

   // create data sources
   int numOfPoints = categories.length;
   String categoryDataRange = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 0, 0));
   String valuesDataRangeA = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 1, 1));
   XDDFDataSource<String> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories, categoryDataRange, 0);
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> valuesDataA = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(valuesA, valuesDataRangeA, 1);

   // create axis
   XDDFCategoryAxis categoryAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   categoryAxis.setTickLabelPosition(AxisTickLabelPosition.NONE);
   XDDFValueAxis valueAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
   valueAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
   // Set AxisCrossBetween, so the left axis crosses the category axis between the categories.
   // Else first and last category is exactly on cross points and the bars are only half visible.
   valueAxis.setCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.BETWEEN);

   // create chart data
   XDDFBarChartData data = (XDDFBarChartData)chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, categoryAxis, valueAxis);
   data.setBarDirection(BarDirection.BAR);

   // create series
   data.setVaryColors(true);
   XDDFBarChartData.Series series = (XDDFBarChartData.Series)data.addSeries(categoriesData, valuesDataA);
   // XDDFChart.setSheetTitle is buggy. It creates a Table but only half way and incomplete.
   // Excel cannot opening the workbook after creating that incomplete Table.
   // So updating the chart data in Word is not possible.
   //series.setTitle("Ser1", chart.setSheetTitle("Ser1", 1));
   series.setTitle("Ser1", setTitleInDataSheet(chart, "Ser1", 1));
   // since apache oi 4.1.1 XDDFChart does not fill the series in the sheet while plot. Apache poi 4.1.0 had done this: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_0/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFChart.java?view=markup#l363
   // so we need doing this for each series now
   fillSheet(chart, categoriesData, valuesDataA);

   // plot chart data
   chart.plot(data);

   // Write the output to a file
   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordXDDFChart.docx")) {
    document.write(fileOut);
   }
  }
 }
}
```